# Jaspersoft: Web Server not showing HTML, but PDF shows

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm having an issue with a report where the HTML version shown on the server will not show the value of a sub report, it's simply the name of an employee, but if you export as PDF then it shows correctly.

I was expecting it to be an error with Fonts, but I've tried changing the font multiple times, but still it isn't showing correctly.

I have another report which makes use of the same subreport and it shows the HTML version fine, the only difference is the one that works uses a cross tab and the one which doesn't uses a table.

Has anyone had a similar issue, if so what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the issue lies within the table, though the exact reason as to why this is the case I'm still unsure.

As I am only ever wanting to return a single line I can instead put the fields directly into the detail band, the sub-report will the correctly show the name.